# Globalize gem: to use or not to use?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-5, globalize

I have a active model named "references" and its data structure is as below:

```
id         :integer          not null, primary key
title      :text(65535)
created_at :datetime         not null
updated_at :datetime         not null
```

As you can see title is the only text for translation.  In fact I have 983 titles are in English, but 17 titles in Japanese.  For Japanese customer, I can show those 17 titles in Japanese without problem.  But for English customer, I need to translate those 17 titles in English.

At first, I plan to create CSV file named reference_translation to have total 2000 records (983 English titles + 17 Japanese titles plus 983 English titles + 17 translated English titles).  But I don't think it is right way to do it.  Thus I try to use Globalize gem, but not sure if it is the right solution for this case.

I think Globalize gem can help me to create the translation file quickly by following the instructions in Globalize README file.  I think the fallback is good, so that I don't have to store all 2000 records in CSV, perhaps just 1017 records (983 English titles, 17 Japanese titles plus 17 translated titles).  In future, I only need to translate those 17 Japanese titles to other languages without keep creating 1000 records in CSV.

Am my thinking correctly?  Or is there other way to do it more efficiently?  Please advise.  Thank you.